# Replace a string value with another string in a column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file which contains date, location and health status.

```
Date         Location            Health
2018-02-11   DELHI               OK
2018-02-11   MUMBAI              not responding
2018-02-11   KOLKATA             ok
2018-02-11   PUNE                ok
2018-02-11   CHENNAI             not responding
2018-02-11   NOIDA               OK
2018-02-11   GURGAON             not responding
2018-02-11   CHANDIGARH          ok
```

I want the strings `ok` in the **Health** column to be capitalized but as you can see, there are certain lowercase representations as well.How do I ensure the lowercase string `ok` is changed to upercase string `OK`?

I have used this function below

```
df = pd.read_csv("metrics.csv", parse_dates=["date"])
df['Health'].replace("ok", "OK", inplace=True)
```

But it still shows the lowercase ok.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `df['Health'] = df['Health'].str.strip().replace("ok", "OK")` ?

Comment: @jpp tried yours...doesn't work

Comment: How about `df.loc[df['Health']=='ok', 'Health'] = 'OK'` ?

Comment: @jpp sorry but this doesn't work either

Comment: @jpp I am sorry but your first solution actually worked.For some reason, I couldn't see it yesterday.You may post this as an answer and I will accept the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that replace ok with OK

```
def replaceword(ok):
    if ok in 'ok':
        ok = 'OK'
        return ok
    else: 
        return ok
```

then use apply

```
df['Health'] = df['Health'].apply(replaceword)
```